# Use onClick event (or trigger of a function) as useEffect dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

As I understand it, passing an array of states as dependencies in a useEffect function results in the function only being called when those specific states change.

I have a function (handleClick) that is called in response to an onClick event. This triggers a change in state. I then wish call a useEffect function that makes additional changes to that state, depending on its content. I must call the additional function inside a useEffect, as the component must re-render (and the state update) for this functions to work as intended.

Given that this additional function also changes the state, I cannot use the state as a dependency for the useEffect (as it will trigger an infinite loop). Therefore, I was wondering if it were possible to trigger the useEffect using a the onClick event (or something along those lines).

The below code is an extract. I apologise that it is not really reproducible.

```
function handleClick(event){
        let button = event.target.id // Set button to element (button) id

        if (button !== 'all'){ // Executes if button is not the "all subjects" button
            if (subjects[button] === 'active'){ // If button is currently active, set to inactive
                setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [button]: 'inactive'}))
            } else { // If button is currently inactive, set to active
                setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [button]: 'active'}))
            }
        } else { // Executes if button is the "all subjects" button
            if (subjects["all"] === 'active'){ // If "all" button is currently active...
                for (let subject in subjects){ // ...inactivate all subjects
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [subject]: 'inactive'}))
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, all: 'inactive'}))
                } 
            } else { // If "all" button is not currently active...
                for (let subject in subjects){ // ...activate all subjects
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [subject]: 'active'}))
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, all: 'active'}))
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    function checkAll(){
        setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, all: 'active'})) // Set "all" button to active by default

        for (let subject in subjects){ // Iterate through object to find inactive subjects
            if (subject !== "all"){ // Excludes "all" button
                if (subjects[subject] === 'inactive'){ // If any subject is inactive...
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, all: 'inactive'})) // ...inactivate "all" button
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I have the useEffect – I have put the handleClick function as the dependency, to indicate what I am intending.

```
useEffect(() => checkAll(), [handleClick])
```

**EDIT**

I originally had my code structured as such:

```
function handleClick(event){
        let button = event.target.id // Set button to element (button) id

        if (button !== 'all'){ // Executes if button is not the "all subjects" button
            if (subjects[button] === 'active'){ // If button is currently active, set to inactive
                setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [button]: 'inactive'}))
            } else { // If button is currently inactive, set to active
                setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [button]: 'active'}))
            }

            setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, all: 'active'})) // Set "all" button to active by default

            for (let subject in subjects){ // Iterate through object to find inactive subjects
                if (subject !== "all"){ // Excludes "all" button
                    if (subjects[subject] === 'inactive'){ // If any subject is inactive...
                        setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, all: 'inactive'})) // ...inactivate "all" button
                    }
                }
            }

        } else { // Executes if button is the "all subjects" button
            if (subjects["all"] === 'active'){ // If "all" button is currently active...
                for (let subject in subjects){ // ...inactivate all subjects
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [subject]: 'inactive'}))
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, all: 'inactive'}))
                } 
            } else { // If "all" button is not currently active...
                for (let subject in subjects){ // ...activate all subjects
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [subject]: 'active'}))
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, all: 'active'}))
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

'subjects' is a object (state variable) structured as such:

```
const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState({all: inactive, button1: inactive, button2: inactive, button3: inactive, button4: inactive, button5: inactive, button6: inactive})
```

When a button is clicked, the ID of which corresponds to one of the keys in the object, it switches from active to inactive (or vice versa). If all buttons are active, the 'all' button is set to active also. If not, the 'all' button is inactive. The checkAll function in the original question pertains to this test. By default, it is set to active, then the buttons are iterated through to check if any are inactive.

However, I would find that with the above (edited) code, if all but one buttons were active and I activated the last button, the all button would not activate (and if I console.logged the state, it would state that the last button was still inactive). If I then inactivated a button, the 'all' button would activate. Hence, the 'all' button would always seem to lag behind by one render.

Comment: It seems like you should just implement the `checkAll` logic in the `handleClick` function.  There is no need to modify the state again in a separate function (that I can tell).

Comment: I agree with @PsiKai.  You could also use `useReducer` instead of `useState` to change "another part of state".

Comment: @PsiKai Thank you for your suggestion, I’ll give it a try. My initial issue with the putting checkAll logic within the handleClick function was the the state always seemed to be one step behind (i.e it wasn’t until I clicked another button that ‘subjects’ reflected the change, thus checkAll was not working). I’ll see if reordering things and a few console.logs identity where I was going wrong.

Comment: If you would like to edit your question with what you have tried, I can help you debug it.

Comment: @PsiKai Thank you so much for your help. I have updated the question with additional code and explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have found, it is only possible to use states as dependencies for useEffect. Given my state ("state a") additionally updates within the useEffect function, the state cannot be used as a dependency without triggering an infinite loop. As suggested, I could create a separate state ("state b") that updates upon the onClick event. However, having tried this, it appears that the states do not necessarily update in the order that they are written (correct me if I am wrong). As such, I would find that "state b" would update before "state a", resulting in the useEffect triggering before "state a" has updated (upon which the logic within the useEffect is dependent). I have not figured out how to solve this. I believe that these issues arise because setState is asynchronous. Thus, wrapping the function in a promise and awaiting the resolve may work, though I have not attempted it.

Nonetheless, I have now solved my initial issue by placing the checkAll logic within the setState callback, such that the the logic only runs when the previous state update has occurred. The below code now functions as intended.

```
function handleClick(event){
        let button = event.target.id // Set button to element (button) id
        
        setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [button]: subjects[button] === 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active'}))

        if (button !== 'all'){ // Executes if any button except the all subjects button is clicked

            setSubjects(prevSubjects => { // Test if 'all' button should be active (requires callback in order to account for pressed button)
                let inactiveSubjects = 0 // Count inactive subjects (0 by default)

                for (let subject in prevSubjects){ // Iterate through subjects
                    if (subject !== "all"){ // Excludes "all" button
                        if (prevSubjects[subject] === 'inactive'){ // If any subject is inactive...
                            inactiveSubjects++ // ... increment inactiveSubjects by 1
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (inactiveSubjects > 0){ // If any subjects are inactive...
                    return {...prevSubjects, 'all': 'inactive'} // ...inactivate the "all" button
                } else {
                    return {...prevSubjects, 'all': 'active'} // ... else activate the "all" button
                }
            })

        } else { // Executes all subjects button is clicked
            if (subjects["all"] === 'active'){ // If "all" button is currently active...
                for (let subject in subjects){ // ...inactivate all subjects
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [subject]: 'inactive'}))
                } 
            } else { // If "all" button is not currently active...
                for (let subject in subjects){ // ...activate all subjects
                    setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({...prevSubjects, [subject]: 'active'}))
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

**Thank you to those that commented. This is an issue that has been bugging me for days.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the `useEffect()` hook on an onClick() event, you can create a state and update the state on click event, and use the state as a dependency to the `useEffect()`.

```
function App() {
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [inpName, setInpName] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("here it ranned")
}, [name]);

 return (
  <div className="App">
   <p>{name}</p>
    <input onChange={(e) => setInpName(e.target.value)} />
    <button onClick={() => setName(inpName)}>click</button>
  </div>
 );
}
```

In this example the `useEffect()` hook will run once when the component mounts and after whenever the name state is updated using click event.

Comment: But they want to update the `subjects` state in the useEffect.  This will cause an infinite re-render.

Comment: @PsiKai Since if you use `useEffect()` for both to set the state and as a dependency, it will surely go into an infinite loop. That's why I am suggesting an extra state to re-render since the state will not be updated without the condition or on the mounting phase. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm seeing from your edit, you were trying to set state multiple times in one function.  The state updates should happen in one call to the setter within the context of a function.  So I took your logic and reduced to one if/else statement that sets state only once.

```
function handleClick(event){
    let button = event.target.id
    function anyActive() {
        for (let subject in subjects){
            if (subject !== "all" && subject === 'inactive') {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    if (button !== 'all') {
        setSubjects(prevSubjects => ({
            ...prevSubjects,
            all: anyActive() ? "inactive" : "active",
            [button]: button === 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active'
        }))
    } else {
        let subjectsCopy
        for (let subject in subjects) {
            subjectsCopy[subject] = subjects["all"] === "inactive" ? "active" : "inactive"
        }
        setSubjects(subjectsCopy)
    }
}
```

I made use of the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to set 'active' or 'inactive' state based on your previous if statements.  I also extracted the loop into a helper function to return true if one of the non-all buttons are inactive  This is what allows me to get it all done in one state set.

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work in my application; the all button still seemed to be one step behind. However, the changes you have suggested allowed me to fix my code (see the answer I have posted), for which I am really appreciative.